# Typescript - Duplicate Identifier on everything

Tags: android, angular, typescript, nativescript

I ran into a bit of an issue with my NS NG2 app. Whenever I try to run the command `tns livesync android --watch`, or any other command to build, I receive a very long list of errors. Below is a small snippet of this error.

```
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20054,15): error TS2451: Cannot red
eclare block-scoped variable 'name'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20328,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'AAGUID'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20329,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'AlgorithmIdentifier'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20330,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'ConstrainBoolean'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20331,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'ConstrainDOMString'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20332,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'ConstrainDouble'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20333,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'ConstrainLong'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20334,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'CryptoOperationData'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20335,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'GLbitfield'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20336,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'GLboolean'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20337,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'GLbyte'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20338,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'GLclampf'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20339,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'GLenum'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20340,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'GLfloat'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20341,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'GLint'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20342,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'GLintptr'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20343,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'GLshort'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20344,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'GLsizei'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20345,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'GLsizeiptr'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20346,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'GLubyte'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20347,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'GLuint'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20348,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'GLushort'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20349,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'IDBKeyPath'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20350,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'KeyFormat'.
app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20351,6): error TS2300: Duplicate i
dentifier 'KeyType'.
```

This is just a *very* small sample of the errors I am receiving.

This happened when I went to work on my mac and then transferred to my PC. I pulled the small code changes I made (have already tried to reverse these) and tried to build. That is when I was met with this error list. I am going to list a few files below that may help in finding the answer.

package.json

```
{
  "description": "AppName",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "AppName",
  "repository": "myRepo",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.appName",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "2.4.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "2.4.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.1.2",
    "email-validator": "^1.0.7",
    "nativescript-angular": "1.1.3",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "^1.3.3",
    "nativescript-loading-indicator": "^2.2.1",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.2.1",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^3.7.1",
    "nativescript-telerik-ui": "^1.4.1",
    "nativescript-toasty": "^1.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "tns-core-modules": "2.4.0",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.19.0",
    "babel-types": "6.19.0",
    "babylon": "6.11.0",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "filewalker": "0.1.2",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "zone.js": "~0.6.21"
  }
}
```

references.d.ts

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-core-modules/tns-core-modules.d.ts" /> Needed for autocompletion and compilation.
/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-core-modules/tns-core-modules.es6.d.ts" />

/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android/android17.d.ts" />

/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android/org.nativescript.widgets.d.ts" />
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2016"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "platforms"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, I went through every single line of my package.json and looked up each module. Checked for their recent updates and set it to install a version last updated about 20 days ago. For each one. After deleting my node modules and doing `npm install` 4 times, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of your other files includes a reference to `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts` and other `.d.ts` files. I've tried to reproduce the same error, with a newly created project based on your package.json and tsconfig.json, but no matter of my configuration, the `lib.es6.d.ts` had never been included in the transpilation.

You should check all of your files for references to `.d.ts` files in `node_modules`. It looks like some of them conflict with each other.

Also you can try deleting your `node_modules` directory and execute `tns build android` again.

One more note - `tns-platform-declarations` should be devDependency - it's used only for autocompletion and transpilation, you do not need it on the device.

Comment: I am surprised you could not duplicate the issue. I just did. Created a project using tns create appname --ng, then put in my ref and package files, and it has the exact same issue. However I have been unable to figure out what about these files is causing this

Answer (score 0):

It could be that one of the references you are including is exporting es6 typings which is conflicting with the built in es6 typings.

Take out the references comments and see if you still have the duplicate identifier issues.

Also try taking out the lib: ["es6"] since something else is already importing the es6 typings.

The new version of typescript can load types from npm modules if they are exports.

You can set `moduleResulotion: "node"` in your compilerOptions and use es6 imports to load the .d.ts files in different parts of your project.

Comment: error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'moduleResulotion'. - when trying your last idea